# Azure DevOps Pipeline Global Package Installs Best Practices

Tags: node.js, npm, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

For our pipeline we have two windows self-hosted agents installed on the same computer. Our main front-end pipeline .yml is listed below. This works fine except for some reason the `npm install` doesn't get nx, or jest. To fix this we can just run `npm install -g nx` and `npm install -g jest` once in the pipeline for each agent. After the first run it is fine and we can remove the extra installs to speed up execution. However, it won't update when new versions of nx or jest are released and this definitely isn't best practices.

I am guessing the problem is that these need to be install globally to work so the regular `npm install` can't achieve that. I included a slightly modified version of our `package.json` which shows that nx (@nrwl) and jest are included in the package. Does anyone know a better way to install the nx and jest without reinstalling them each pipeline build and without removing install statements after the first run with a new agent? Thank you in advance for any suggestions, please let me know if I can provide any additional information.

```
trigger:
- none

pool: 'myPool'
variables:
  npm_config_cache: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/.npm

steps:
- checkout: self
  clean: true

- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '12.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

# Install stuff
- task: Npm@1
  timeoutInMinutes: 10
  inputs:
    command: 'install'
    workingDir: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/ID_CLIENT'
  displayName: 'npm install'

# Test stuff
- script: nx affected:lint --base=origin/master --skip-nx-cache=true --parallel
  timeoutInMinutes: 10
  workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/ID_CLIENT'
  displayName: 'run lint'

- script: 'jest --ci --reporters=default --reporters=jest-junit'
  timeoutInMinutes: 10
  workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/ID_CLIENT'
  displayName: 'Run Tests'
  continueOnError: 'true'

# Build stuff
- script: nx affected:build --base=origin/master --skip-nx-cache=true --parallel
  timeoutInMinutes: 10
  workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/ID_CLIENT'
  displayName: 'prod build'

# Publish test results to Azure Pipelines
- task: PublishTestResults@2
  timeoutInMinutes: 10
  inputs:
    testResultsFormat: 'JUnit'
    testResultsFiles: '**/junit.xml' 
    searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    failTaskOnFailedTests: true
```

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "install:hard": "rimraf \"node_modules/!(rimraf)\" && npm cache clear --force && npm install",
    "install:globals": "npm install -g jest-cli @nrwl/cli",
    "postinstall": "ngcc"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.1.4",
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.4",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.4",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.4",
    "@angular/localize": "^9.1.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.4",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.4",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^6.1.0",
    "@ngneat/until-destroy": "^7.3.0",
    "angular-datatables": "^9.0.1",
    "angulartics2": "^9.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "core-js": "^3.1.4",
    "jest-junit": "^12.0.0",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nrwl/angular": "^10.3.0",
    "@nrwl/jest": "^10.3.0",
    "@nrwl/workspace": "^10.3.0",
    "jest": "^26.4.2",
    "jest-canvas-mock": "^2.3.0",
    "jest-cli": "^26.4.2",
    "jest-preset-angular": "^8.3.1",
    "jest-skipped-reporter": "0.0.5",
    "ts-jest": "^26.4.1",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3",
  }
}
```

**Edit:** I tried adding `"nx": "^10.3.0"` and `"@nrwl/cli": "^10.3.0"` to the dev dependencies and then after installing I ran `npm run nx test`. It gave me `npm ERR! missing script: nx`. Did I just not add it correctly?

Comment: `nx` and `jest` versions should be locked in the package.json and not installed globally, that's definitely easier to maintain. Not 100% sure on the following but looks like you can include `nx` in `devDependencies` too. Then in your `script` call, instead of `nx affected:lint ...` do `npm run nx affected:lint`. Let us know how it goes.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't seem to work, I described what I tried in my updated post. If I didn't do it correctly let me know and I can try it a different way.

Comment: You can either add an alias to your `package.json`: `"scripts": { "nx": "nx" }` and use `npm run nx affected:lint`. Or try `npx nx affected:lint` if you have npm that is fresh enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with Max Ivanov's solution. We just added nx and the alias to the package.json and switched our pipeline scripts to use `npm run nx ...`.

This has worked really well for us but I'd like to thank Krzysztof Madej and julie-ng for their answers. Both of which are very reasonable and would achieve what we wanted. I ended up not going with them because they don't fit our specific use case as well. If anyone is looking through this post I'd recommend looking at all the answers and picking the one that works best for you.

Answer (score 2):

Well if you want to keep your global tools up to date and avoid running those command each time when your pipeline runs, create a new scheduled pipeline to run it once per day and to update your global tools.

Here you have [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) about scheduled triggers.

But it may look like this:

```yaml
schedules:
- cron: "0 0 * * *"
  displayName: Daily midnight build
  branches:
    include:
    - master
  always: true

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '12.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'
- script: npm install -g jest-cli @nrwl/cli
```

Answer (score 1):

The downside with automatically updating tools like that is things will break - without you knowing it - and rolling back is challenging.

Yes, it's best practice to have latest updates, esp. for bug fixes, etc. But medium term success also means stability via pinning (major/minor) versions is key when projects are in production. It's a bit more overhead to create your own images, but not much more if you're already using self-hosted agents.

**NPX**

Npx is intended to be used globally and since you are using self-hosted agents, create custom a custom agent image, pre-installed with the npx versions you want. Here is an example [Azure Documentation about creating a custom image with Docker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/docker?view=azure-devops#linux). You can also use a VM image.

Then in your pipeline, specify which one you want in your pipeline YAML:

```
pool: 'npx-9'
```

Others can choose a different version

```
pool: 'npx-10'
```

You can choose whatever image name you want. This lets developers choose what they need.

**jest**

Why do you need to install this globally?

Jest should be project specific, listed as a dev dependency in the project's `package.json`, and called via an npm script, e.g. `npm run tests`.

Comment: We are installing jest globally because `npm run tests` didn't properly report the tests. So we had to use `jest --ci --reporters=default --reporters=jest-junit` which would report the tests in Azure DevOps as we would expect. There might be a better solution but I wasn't able to figure it out.

Comment: What wasn't reported? The test results themselves? Or are you referring to the code coverage? I would also double check the configuration and compare versions.

Comment: I found a work around that doesn't require the global download of jest. However, I am referring to the test results themselves. When we use `npm run tests` it just runs the script `nx affected:test --parallel --maxParallel=4`. This doesn't actually create a report, it just displays the information. I get this warning message in Azure DevOps on my publish task when I don't use jest: `##[warning]No test result files matching **/junit.xml were found.` Am I just not setting something up correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Nx has a script called `.azure-pipelines/steps/install-node-modules.yml`
It caches the Node modules each run and checks to see if the cache was retrieved before it tries to `npm install`

This works fine but you will run into the same problems where outdated modules will be used ahead of the newer version.

Below is my modification of the npm install script:

```
- script: npm --prefix "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Code/NxWorkspace" install "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Code/NxWorkspace" --prefer-offline --no-audit --no-progress
  displayName: Install Node Modules
```

Instead of asking if the cache has been restored, I run:
`npm install --prefer-offline --no-audit --no-progress`

`--prefer-offline` prioritizes the cached packages, and will not try to install packages it can already find cached. If the version is bumped, the newer version is installed instead.